# Check Hours in a date format

Tags: php

I have to do the following,

My date have two formats as `Y-m-d H:i:s` and `Y-m-d`

My requirement is,

if date contains Hours(`H`), need to convert to `F j, Y, g:i a`

else to `F j, Y`

Is there any method that I can check `H` in `Y-m-d H:i:s`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `strstr()` to see if there's a space in the date.

Comment: I tried as `strstr($date, date("H", strtotime($date)))` and is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Y-m-d` date format is `10` chars in length and `Y-m-d H:i:s` date format is `19` chars in length . Based on the length you can find if it has a date part . Even if it is 19 chars in length , the time part could be 0 in which case you would disregard the time part . Along this lines should work :

```
//  $date = "2013-09-26";
//  $date = "2013-09-26 00:00:00";
    $date = "2013-09-26 00:00:01";

if( strlen( $date ) == 10 )
{
//  Include code to convert the date to F j, Y
    echo $date , ' Does not have time part .'; 
}
else
{
    if(  strlen( $date ) == 19 and substr( $date, 10, 8 ) <> '00:00:00' )
    {
    //  Include code to convert the date to F j, Y, g:i a
        echo $date , ' Has time part which is not 0 .';
    }
    else
    {
    //  Include code to convert the date to F j, Y
        echo $date , ' Has time part but is 0 .';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
if(strstr($date, ' ') !== FALSE) {
    $date = date('F j, Y, g:i a', strtotime($date));
} else {
    $date = date('F j, Y', strtotime($date));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something i use when getting a date from a db that may or may not come with the time. modify as needed.

```
IF(
    TIME( {$val['field_name']} ) = '00:00:00',
    DATE_FORMAT(DATE( {$val['field_name']} ),'%D %M %Y'),
    DATE_FORMAT({$val['field_name']},'%l:%i%p, %D %M %Y')
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a little verbose - as @Bamar said you can just check for spaces, but this will work even if there are leading or trailing spaces in the field:

```
$date_format = "\s*\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\s*";
$date_time_format = "\s*\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\s\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\s*";
if(preg_match($date_time_format, $subject)){
    $subject = date('F j, Y, g:i a', strtotime($subject));
}
elseif(preg_match($date_format, $subject)){
    $subject = date('F j, Y', strtotime($subject));
}
else{
    //formatting error - you can decide how to format.
}
```